# ‎Access Denied, Due to organizational policies, you can't access this resource from this untrusted device

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I can't view my SharePoint page and SharePoint admin center. I think I was changing some policies at sharepoint admin center, but I can't remember which one I changed. Other admin centers like OneDrive opens without any issue. Even as a admin I can't open SharePoint Admin Center. It says Access Denied, Due to organizational policies, you can't access this resource from this untrusted device. I've cleared my browser's cache and switched different browser but nothing works.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Microsoft support and no response from them, I've tried solving this on my own. Here is how I solved it. Install the SharePoint Powershell from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices#limit-access-using-powershell.)

After installing run these steps on SharePoint Powershell(Admin) to remove access blocks,

1. Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
2. Set-SPOTenant -IPAddressEnforcement 1
3. Set-SPOTenant -IPAddressAllowList (Your current IP address),
   after running these command you will be able to access sharepoint without any issue. Now open SharePoint Admin center and **Policies--> Access Control--> Unmanaged Devices** and select **Allow full access** and save.

Answer (score 0):

Or instead Go in Azure AD if you have And into security option check for conditional Access policies if there is any check if that policy is blocking your access to that website.